# Find the first non repeating character in a string

Tags: java, string

I m writing a method to find the first non repeating character in a string. I saw this method in a previous stackoverflow question

```
public static char findFirstNonRepChar(String input){
 char currentChar = '\0';
 int len = input.length();
 for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    currentChar = input.charAt(i);
    if((i!=0) && (currentChar!=input.charAt(i-1)) && (i==input.lastIndexOf(currentChar))){
        return currentChar;
    }
 }
 return currentChar;
}
```

I came up with a solution using a hashtable where I have two for loops (not nested) where I interate through the string in one loop writing down each occurance of a letter (for example in apple, a would have 1, p would have 2, etc.) then in the second loop I interate through the hashtable to see which one has a count of 1 first. What is the benefit to the above method over what I came up with? I am new to Java does having two loops (not nested) hinder time complexity. Both these algorithms should have O(n) right? Is there another faster, less space complexity algorithm for this question than these two solutions?

Comment: iterate through the hashtable to see which one has a count of 1 *first*. You mean iterate over the String? Because "first" and "no defined iteration order" (for a HashMap) don't mix well.

Comment: Complexity-wise, I think both algorithm are O(n^2) as there are two loops: once for every character and then for that character iterate the string again to see if it appears again. (`lastIndexOf` hides that second loop)

Comment: You didn't supply us with enough information. Are `d` and `D` repeating characters, or different? Also, I initially took 'repeating' as two of the same character being next to eachother. You should make that clear in your post.

Comment: assume everything is lower case

Comment: I would try to prepare some tuple for each character found, storing the character itself, its first position and its 'duplicated' status. For every character in the input string I'd first lookup a storage (a hashmap...?) for a tuple representing the character; if it's found, set a 'duplicated' status, otherwise add <char, pos, false> tuple to the storage. Finally search the storage for a '!duplicated' tuple with the smallest 'pos'. I'm not sure, however, if that can be done with a hashmap...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you asked if your code is from `O(n)` or not, I think it's not, because in the for loop, you are calling `lastIndexOf` and it's worst case is `O(n)`. So it is from `O(n^2)`.

About your second question: having two loops which are not nested, also makes it from `O(n)`.

If assuming non unicode characters in your input String, and Uppercase or Lowercase characters are assumed to be different, the following would do it with o(n) and supports all ASCII codes from `0` to `255`:

```
public static Character getFirstNotRepeatedChar(String input) {

    byte[] flags = new byte[256]; //all is initialized by 0 

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) { // O(n)
        flags[(int)input.charAt(i)]++ ;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) { // O(n)
        if(flags[(int)input.charAt(i)] > 0)
            return input.charAt(i);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Thanks to **Konstantinos Chalkias** hint about the overflow, if your input string has more than 127 occurrence of a certain character, you can change the type of `flags` array from `byte[]` to `int[]` or `long[]` to prevent the overflow of `byte` type.

Hope it would be helpful.

Comment: The problem with this implementation is if you choose characters with int values greater than 256 (in Java, that's possible). But in C++, this code works fine.

Comment: @Paulo: Thanks, thats right, but he mentioned they are all lowercase, and because of that I wrote that code ;-) I mentioned the the input should contains only non-unicode chars.

Comment: That's right. I didn't see his comments at the time I wrote. Now I see this is a solution with very good space and time complexity. :)

Comment: @Paulo: The question body is somehow confusing. Thanks for your support.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to return the first non-repeating character, but the smaller non-repeating one.

Comment: @KonstantinosChalkias: Oh my bad, you are right. Working on it.

Comment: @KonstantinosChalkias: Please consider my edit. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I suppose that I mentioned that we assume the input string characters to be lowercases (as it mentioned in the question). So the overflow is never happens.

Comment: the overflow is not there, I am not referring to the character set. Imagine that you have 257 occurrences of a certain character, then your byte value will be 1 again, causing a false positive!

Comment: Ok, thats right. It was all about the approach not the exact code. What if I change the type of the array to int or long. It would be ok then? I think the question was about the time complexity, or am I missing a point?

Comment: I think OP refers to space complexity too

Comment: Why this answer marked as correct one? When the answer is not correct.

Answer (score 12):

```
public class FirstNonRepeatCharFromString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "java";
        for(Character ch:s.toCharArray()) {
            if(s.indexOf(ch) == s.lastIndexOf(ch)) {
                System.out.println("First non repeat character = " + ch);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, You need to add comment to your code to make your answer useful. Read [answer] to get all detail. Regards

Comment: Elegant! This solution works on the fact that If the first index of the character is also the last index of that character then it means this character is not repeating

Comment: This is definitely not O(n), especially since you read the string once for each character. So we're still in O(n²) with this solution.

Answer (score 7):

The algorithm you showed is slow: it looks for each character in the string, it basically means that for each character you spend your time checking the string twice!! Huge time loss.

The best naive O(n) solution basically holds all the characters in order of insertion (so the *first* can be found) and maps a mutable integer to them. When we're done, analyzing, we go through all the entries and return the first character that was registered and has a count of 1.

There are no restrictions on the characters you can use. And `AtomicInteger` is available with `import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`.

Using Java 8:

```
public static char findFirstNonRepChar(String string) {
    Map<Integer,Long> characters = string.chars().boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
    return (char)(int)characters.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1L)
            .findFirst()
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No unrepeated character"));
}
```

Non Java 8 equivalent:

```
public static char findFirstNonRepChar(String string) {
  Map<Character, AtomicInteger> characters = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // preserves order of insertion.
  for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    char c = string.charAt(i);
    AtomicInteger n = characters.get(c);
    if (n == null) {
      n = new AtomicInteger(0);
      characters.put(c, n);
    }
    n.incrementAndGet();
  }
  for (Map.Entry<Character, AtomicInteger> entry: characters.entries()) {
    if (entry.getValue().get() == 1) {
      return entry.getKey();
    }
  }
  throw new RuntimeException("No unrepeated character");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class getFirstNonRep {

public static char get(String s) throws Exception {
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Fail");
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        Map<Character, Integer> m = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (m.containsKey(s.charAt(i))) {
                m.put(s.charAt(i), m.get(s.charAt(i)) + 1);
            } else {
                m.put(s.charAt(i), 1);
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> hm : m.entrySet()) {
            if (hm.getValue() == 1) {
                return hm.getKey();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.print(get("Youssef Zaky"));

    }

 }
```

This solution takes less space and less time, since we iterate the string only one time.

Answer (score 1):

Works for any type of characters.

```
String charHolder;  // Holds 
String testString = "8uiuiti080t8xt8t";
char   testChar = ' ';
int count = 0;  

for (int i=0; i <= testString.length()-1; i++) {
    testChar = testString.charAt(i);

    for (int j=0; j < testString.length()-1; j++) {
        if (testChar == testString.charAt(j)) {
           count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 1) { break; };
       count = 0;
}

System.out.println("The first not repeating character is " + testChar);
```

Answer (score 1):

I accumulated all possible methods with string length 25'500 symbols:

```
private static String getFirstUniqueChar(String line) {
    String result1 = null, result2 = null, result3 = null, result4 = null, result5 = null;
    int length = line.length();

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Map<Character, Integer> chars = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
    char[] charArray1 = line.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char currentChar = charArray1[i];
        chars.put(currentChar, chars.containsKey(currentChar) ? chars.get(currentChar) + 1 : 1);
    }
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : chars.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() == 1) {
            result1 = entry.getKey().toString();
            break;
        }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("1st test:\n    result: " + result1 + "\n    time: " + (end - start));

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        String current = Character.toString(line.charAt(i));
        String left = line.substring(0, i);
        if (!left.contains(current)) {
            String right = line.substring(i + 1);
            if (!right.contains(current)) {
                result2 = current;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("2nd test:\n    result: " + result2 + "\n    time: " + (end - start));

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char currentChar = line.charAt(i);
        if (line.indexOf(currentChar) == line.lastIndexOf(currentChar)) {
            result3 = Character.toString(currentChar);
            break;
        }
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("3rd test:\n    result: " + result3 + "\n    time: " + (end - start));

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    char[] charArray4 = line.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char currentChar = charArray4[i];
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (currentChar == charArray4[j] && i != j) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            result4 = Character.toString(currentChar);
            break;
        }
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("4th test:\n    result: " + result4 + "\n    time: " + (end - start));

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char currentChar = line.charAt(i);
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (currentChar == line.charAt(j) && i != j) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            result5 = Character.toString(currentChar);
            break;
        }
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("5th test:\n    result: " + result5 + "\n    time: " + (end - start));

    return result1;
}
```

And time results (5 times):

```
1st test:
    result: g
    time: 13, 12, 12, 12, 14
2nd test:
    result: g
    time: 55, 56, 59, 70, 59
3rd test:
    result: g
    time: 2, 3, 2, 2, 3
4th test:
    result: g
    time: 3, 3, 2, 3, 3
5th test:
    result: g
    time: 6, 5, 5, 5, 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static char NonReapitingCharacter(String str) {
        Set<Character> s = new HashSet();
        char ch = '\u0000';
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (s.add(c)) {
                
                if (c == ch) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    ch = c;
                }
            }
        }
        return ch;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I misread the question initially so here's a new solution. I believe is this O(n). The `contains(Object)` of `HashSet` is O(1), so we can take advantage of that and avoid a second loop. Essentially if we've never seen a specific `char` before, we add it to the `validChars` as a potential candidate to be returned. The second we see it again however, we add it to the trash can of `invalidChars`. This prevents that char from being added again. At the end of the loop (you **have** to loop at least once no matter what you do), you'll have a `validChars` hashset with `n` amount of elements. If none are there, then it will return `null` from the Character class. This has a distinct advantage as the `char` class has no good way to return a 'bad' result so to speak.

```
public static Character findNonRepeatingChar(String x)
{
    HashSet<Character> validChars = new HashSet<>();
    HashSet<Character> invalidChars = new HashSet<>(); 

    char[] array = x.toCharArray();
    for (char c : array)
    {
        if (validChars.contains(c))
        {
            validChars.remove(c);
            invalidChars.add(c);
        }
        else if (!validChars.contains(c) && !invalidChars.contains(c))
        {
            validChars.add(c);
        }
    }

    return (!validChars.isEmpty() ? validChars.iterator().next() : null);
}
```

Comment: good solution but watch out that the time is going to be catastrophic in worst case that the non-rep character is at the end of an extremely long String ! Plus your final loop will do some useless operations. Example, if we have " yosssss", it will loop over each s ! while a loop over 1 s is going to be sufficient. Look at my solution below, the same thing but I used LinkedHashMap to store each character in ORDER since HashMap doesn't store the set <Character,Integer> in order.

Answer (score 0):

In case of two loops (not nested) the time complexity would be O(n).

The second solution mentioned in the question can be implemented as:

We can use string characters as keys to a map and maintain their count. Following is the algorithm.

1.Scan the string from left to right and construct the count map.

2.Again, scan the string from left to right and check for count of each character from the map, if you find an element who’s count is 1, return it.

```
package com.java.teasers.samples;  
import java.util.Map;  
import java.util.HashMap;  
public class NonRepeatCharacter {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String yourString = "Hi this is javateasers";//change it with your string  
        Map<Character, Integer> characterMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();  
        //Step 1 of the Algorithm  
        for (int i = 0; i < yourString.length(); i++) {  
            Character character = yourString.charAt(i);  
            //check if character is already present  
            if(null != characterMap.get(character)){  
                //in case it is already there increment the count by 1.  
                characterMap.put(character, characterMap.get(character) + 1);  
            }  
            //in case it is for the first time. Put 1 to the count  
            else  
                characterMap.put(character, 1);  
        }  
        //Step 2 of the Algorithm  
        for (int i = 0; i < yourString.length(); i++) {  
            Character character = yourString.charAt(i);  
            int count = characterMap.get(character);  
            if(count == 1){  
                System.out.println("character is:" + character);  
                break;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested for characters in the range a-z (lowercase as OP requested in comments), you can use this method that requires a minimum extra storage of two bits per character Vs a HashMap approach.

```
/*
 * It works for lowercase a-z
 * you can scale it to add more characters
 * eg use 128 Vs 26 for ASCII or 256 for extended ASCII 
 */
public static char getFirstNotRepeatedChar(String input) {

    boolean[] charsExist = new boolean[26];
    boolean[] charsNonUnique = new boolean[26];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        int index = 'z' - input.charAt(i);
        if (!charsExist[index]) {
            charsExist[index] = true;
        } else {
            charsNonUnique[index] = true;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (!charsNonUnique['z' - input.charAt(i)])
            return input.charAt(i);
    }

    return '?'; //example return of no character found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public char firstNonRepeatedChar(String input) {
    char out = 0;
    int length = input.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        String sub1 = input.substring(0, i);
        String sub2 = input.substring(i + 1);
        if (!(sub1.contains(input.charAt(i) + "") || sub2.contains(input
                .charAt(i) + ""))) {
            out = input.charAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since LinkedHashMap keeps the order of insertion

```
package com.company;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argh) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String l = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(firstCharNoRepeated(l));
    }

    private static String firstCharNoRepeated(String l) {
        Map<String, Integer> chars = new LinkedHashMap();
        for(int i=0; i < l.length(); i++) {
            String c = String.valueOf(l.charAt(i));
            if(!chars.containsKey(c)){
                chars.put(c, i);
            } else {
                chars.remove(c);
            }
        }
        return chars.keySet().iterator().next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few lines of code, works for me.

```
public class FirstNonRepeatingCharacter {

    final static String string = "cascade";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] charArr = string.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; charArr.length > i; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; charArr.length > j; j++) {
                if (charArr[i] == charArr[j]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == 1){
                System.out.println("First Non Repeating Character is: " + charArr[i]);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraint for this solution:

O(n) time complexity. My solution is O(2n), follow Time Complexity analysis,O(2n) => O(n)

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class FindFirstNonDuplicateCharacter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(findFirstNonDuplicateCharacter("abacbcefd"));
    }

    private static char findFirstNonDuplicateCharacter(String s) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> chDupCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    char[] charArr = s.toCharArray();
    for (char ch: charArr) { //first loop, make the tables and counted duplication by key O(n)
      if (!chDupCount.containsKey(ch)) {
        chDupCount.put(ch,1);
        continue;
      }
      int dupCount = chDupCount.get(ch)+1;
      chDupCount.replace(ch, dupCount);
    }

    char res = '-';
    for(char ch: charArr) { //second loop, get the first duplicate by count number, O(2n)
      // System.out.println("key: " + ch+", value: " + chDupCount.get(ch));
      if (chDupCount.get(ch) == 1) {
        res = ch;
        break;
      }
    }

    return res;
    } 
}
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

```
char firstNotRepeatingCharacter(String s) {
    for(int i=0; i< s.length(); i++){
        if(i == s.lastIndexOf(s.charAt(i)) && i == s.indexOf(s.charAt(i))){
            return s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return '_';
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, code-only answers tend to not be useful to other readers and therefore can attract downvotes. Add some explanation to how your code works and how it's different or better than the other answers and you will have a nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "sampapl";
    char ar[] = a.toCharArray();

    int dya[] = new int[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < dya.length; i++) {
        dya[i] = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {

        if (dya[ar[i]] != -1) {
            System.out.println(ar[i]);
           break;
        } else {
            dya[ar[i]] = ar[i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solution in python:

```
input_str = "interesting"
#input_str = "aabbcc"
#input_str = "aaaapaabbcccq"


def firstNonRepeating(param):
    counts = {}        
    for i in range(0, len(param)):

    # Store count and index repectively
        if param[i] in counts:
            counts[param[i]][0] += 1
        else:
            counts[param[i]] = [1, i]

    result_index = len(param) - 1
    for x in counts:
        if counts[x][0] == 1 and result_index > counts[x][1]:
            result_index = counts[x][1]
    return result_index

result_index = firstNonRepeating(input_str)
if result_index == len(input_str)-1:
    print("no such character found")
else:
    print("first non repeating charater found: " + input_str[result_index])
```

Output:

`first non repeating charater found: r`

Answer (score 0):

```
  import java.util.*;
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str1 = "gibblegabbler";
  System.out.println("The given string is: " + str1);
  for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
   boolean unique = true;
   for (int j = 0; j < str1.length(); j++) {
    if (i != j && str1.charAt(i) == str1.charAt(j)) {
     unique = false;
     break;
    }
   }
   if (unique) {
    System.out.println("The first non repeated character in String is: " + str1.charAt(i));
    break;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: First Non Repeating Character using Array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GFG {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "mmjjjjmmn";
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (s.indexOf(c) == s.lastIndexOf(c)) {
            System.out.println("First non repeated is:" + c);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`output = n`

Answer (score 0):

**Non Repeated Character String in Java**

```
public class NonRepeatedCharacter {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "ffeeddbbaaclck";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
             boolean unique = true;
             for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                 if (i != j && s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                     unique = false;
                     break;
                 }
              }
             if (unique) {
                 System.out.println("First non repeated characted in String \""
                 + s + "\" is:" + s.charAt(i));
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
}
Output:
First non repeated characted in String "ffeeddbbaaclck" is:l
```

[For More Details](http://www.javatechblog.com/java/java-program-to-find-first-non-repeated-character-in-a-string/)

Answer (score 0):

### **In this coding i use length of string to find the first non repeating letter.**

```
 package com.string.assingment3;
    import java.util.Scanner;
   public class FirstNonRepetedChar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a String : ");
        String str = in.next();
        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        int length = ch.length;
        int x = length;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
            x = length-i;
            for(int j=i+1;j<length;j++) {
                if(ch[i]!=ch[j]) {
                    x--;
                }//if
            }//inner for
            if(x==1) {
            System.out.println(ch[i]);
                break;
            }
            else {
                    continue;
            }
        }//outer for
    }
}// develope by NDM
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin

```
 fun firstNonRepeating(string: String): Char?{
    //Get a copy of the string
    var copy = string
    //Slice string into chars then convert them to string
    string.map { it.toString() }.forEach {
        //Replace first occurrance of that character and check if it still has it
        if (copy.replaceFirst(it,"").contains(it))
        //If it has the given character remove it
            copy = copy.replace(it,"")
    }
    //Return null if there is no non-repeating character
    if (copy.isEmpty())
        return null
    //Get the first character from what left of that string
    return copy.first()
}
```

https://pl.kotl.in/KzL-veYNZ

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void firstNonRepeatFirstChar(String str) {

    System.out.println("The given string is: " + str);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        boolean unique = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            if (i != j && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) {
                unique = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (unique) {
            System.out.println("The first non repeated character in String is: " + str.charAt(i));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: code only solutions are discouraged. add some explanations

Answer (score 0):

Using Set with single for loop

public static Character firstNonRepeatedCharacter(String str) {

```
Character result = null;

if (str != null) {
  Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
  for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (set.add(c) && result == null) {
      result = c;
    } else if (result != null && c == result) {
      result = null;
    }
  }
}
return result;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in single traversal of String using LinkedHashSet as follows:

```
    public static Character getFirstNonRepeatingCharacter(String str) {
            Set<Character> result = new LinkedHashSet<>(256);
            for (int i = 0; i< str.length(); ++i) {
                if(!result.add(str.charAt(i))) {
                    result.remove(str.charAt(i));
                }
             }
            if(result.iterator().hasNext()) {
                return result.iterator().next();
             }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java;

```
char firstNotRepeatingCharacter(String s) {
    
    HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
    StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder(s);
    
    for (int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
        char c = sb.charAt(i);
        if(s.indexOf(c) == i && s.indexOf(c, i+1) == -1 ) {
            return c;
        }
    }

    return '_';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FirstNonRepeatingChar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "hello world i am here";

        s.chars().boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1).findFirst().ifPresent(e->System.out.println(e.getKey()));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package looping.concepts;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Line {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String a = sc.nextLine();
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            char ch = a.charAt(i);
            int counter = 0;
            // boolean repeat = false;
            for (j = 0; j < a.length(); j++) {
                if (ch == a.charAt(j)) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if (counter == 1) {
                System.out.print(ch);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("There is no non repeated character");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong Solution because counter can be other then 1 and 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NonRepaeated1
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    String str;
    char non_repeat=0;
    int len,i,j,count=0;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    str = s.nextLine();

    len = str.length();

    for(i=0;i<len;i++) 
    { 
      non_repeat=str.charAt(i); 
      count=1; 

      for(j=0;j<len;j++) 
      { 
        if(i!=j) 
        { 
          if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) 
          { 
            count=0; 
            break; 
          } 
        } 
      } 

      if(count==1) 
        break; 
    } 
if(count == 1) 
System.out.print("The non repeated character is  : " + non_repeat); 

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.test.util;

public class StringNoRepeat {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String st = "234123nljnsdfsdf41l";
        String strOrig=st;
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        String st1="";
        Character ch=' ';
        boolean fnd=false;
        for (i=0;i<strOrig.length(); i++) {


            ch=strOrig.charAt(i);
            st1 = ch.toString();

            if (i==0)
                st = strOrig.substring(1,strOrig.length());
            else if (i == strOrig.length()-1)
            st=strOrig.substring(0, strOrig.length()-1);
            else 
                st=strOrig.substring(0, i)+strOrig.substring(i+1,strOrig.length());
            if (st.indexOf(st1) == -1) {
                fnd=true;
              j=i;
                break;  
            }
        }
        if (!fnd)
            System.out.println("The first no non repeated character");
        else
            System.out.println("The first non repeated character is " +strOrig.charAt(j));


    }

}
```