# looking for the first character non duplicated in a string

Tags: java

hello everybody i need some help this is my code 
( a code about finding the first character not dupplicated ) 
thanks :)

```
package Algo;
import java.lang.String;
public class Algo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //String word = sc.nextLine();
        String str ="Sea";
        if (str.length() == 1) {
            System.out.println("the first non dupplicate charactere is\"+str.charAt(0)");
        }
        while (str != "") {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length(); i++) {
                int j = i++;
                    while (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j+1)) {
                    j++;
                    if (j == str.length()) {
                        System.out.println("the first non dupplicate charactere is"+str.charAt(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151126/find-the-first-non-repeating-character-in-a-string

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151126/find-the-first-non-repeating-character-in-a-string

Comment: Hi Amine, please ask clear and concise questions on StackOverflow that show you've taken serious efforts in researching this problem yourself. A quick Google search yields many results that solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`while(str!="")` will cause an infinite loop since your str never becomes empty. Maybe you wanted to check it with an if statement.
The part of code to do it starting from the `while(str!="")` changed into `else if(str!="")` :

```
else if (str != ""){
    for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++){
        boolean nonDuplicate = false;
        for(int j=i+1;j<str.length();j++){
            if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j))
                break;
            if(j==str.length()-1)
                nonDuplicate=true;
        }
        if(nonDuplicate){
            System.out.println("the first non dupplicate charactere is"+str.charAt(i));
            break;
        }
    }
}
else{
    System.out.println("The string is empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more OOP approach would be a class with static method, which returns specified character. Here I wrote an example of a more procedural approach. It is easier for beginner to understand. In the code comments below i wrote all the necesarry information about how to improve algorithm.

```
package Algo;
// import java.lang.String; // no need to write this, java.lang.String already implicitly imported
public class Algo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //String word = sc.nextLine();
        String str ="Sea";
        if(str==null || str="") System.out.println("Error: You've inputed empty string"); // for future tests, you might accidently press enter in cmd input
        if (str.length() == 1) {
            System.out.println("the first non dupplicate charactere is " + str.charAt(0));
        }
        // while (str != "") {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length(); i++) {
                int j = i+1; // i++ increments variable i and i becomes equal 1, when it should stay 0.
                    while (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j)) { // j+1 - means when i=0, then j=2 and you comparing first character with third
                    j++;
                    if (j == str.length()) {
                        System.out.println("the first non dupplicate charactere is "+str.charAt(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        // }
    }
}
```